# link from div class="overlay" to another page with on-Clickfun

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

i am new to coding and i want to ask, how can I link from my heading to pages,  one word should bring me to my 2nd page and the other to the third page.[this is my main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6qJO.png)

Comment: there are a few methods to do this in the link: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML anchor tags to navigate to different pages.

```
<a href="/page1html">Hajj</a>
<a href="/page2.html">Umra</a>
```